# Loading simple JS code after page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Is there a way to load the JavaScript code (without placing it in the very bottom line of HTML document) after the page has been loaded? Here's the script example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?count=10&display=latest&size=t&layout=x&source=user&user=XXX"></script>
```

PS. the reason is that the above Flickr code loads slowly and hangs the site meanwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Use any event to append the code
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "test.js";
    // Use any selector
    $("head").append(s);
});
</script>
```

off course this will require jquery library or else you can paste this code on body's onload method

well this is something useful

### **It's not possible to synchronously execute a script at a URL. Note further that synchronous anything, when networks (or even file systems!) are involved is a Bad Idea. Someone, sometime, somewhere will be on a slow system, or a slow network, or both, and suddenly you've just hung their UI in the process.**

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6557

alternatively you can try

http://yepnopejs.com/

Comment: Note this requires the jQuery library.

Comment: jquery is tagged as part of the question

Comment: Thanks, but have you tested it? i've tried and it does not work.

Comment: no any error, but doesn't this append mean that it should place the above js src file in the head section of the body? I still see in the body, and also it does not get data from the flickr in this way, while it gets without using this.

Comment: well you can try this also $.getScript("test.js"); on document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Apply it to the body's onload method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a script after the entire page has finished loading (including all the elements) try this. (jQuery)

```
$(window).load(function() {
        var js, 
            id = 'SCRIPT-ID', 
            ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

        if (document.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }

        js = document.createElement('script'); 
        js.id = id; 
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "http://www.website.com/script.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    });
```

If you want it to load once the DOM is rendered, just change `$(window)` to `$(document)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var asyncLoad = function (url) {
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
    return script;
};
```

// or, for scriptless pages, just add to the head;

```
var asyncLoad = function (url) {
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    head.appendChild(script);
    return script;
};
```

// apply:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    asyncLoad('script_url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require modular execution of your scripts you can use following library

http://headjs.com/